# DRF ListView with GeometryFilter

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, geodjango, django-rest-framework-gis

I am writing an API that should return all objects whose geometry intersects the given geometry (EWKT or WKT format, to be defined). I am trying to use [`django-rest-framework-gis.filters`](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis#filters) but not working so far.

What I have tried :

models.py:

```
class GeoData(models.Model):
    geometry = models.GeometryField(srid=3857)
    slug_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

serializers.py:

```
from .models import GeoData

class GeoDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GeoData
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import filters

from .serializers import GeoDataSerializer
from .filters import IntersectionFilter
from .models import GeoData

class GeoDataView(generics.ListAPIView):     
    serializer_class = GeoDataSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, ) 
    filter_class = IntersectionFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = GeoData.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

filters.py:

```
import django_filters 
from rest_framework_gis import filters
from rest_framework_gis.filterset import GeoFilterSet

from .models import GeoData

class IntersectionFilter(GeoFilterSet):
    slug_name = django_filters.CharFilter(name='slug_name', lookup_type='exact')
    geometry = filters.GeometryFilter(name='geometry', lookup_type='intersects')

    filter_overrides = {}

    class Meta:
        model = GeoData
```

Now when calling my url:
`http://localhost:8000/geodata/?geometry='LINESTRING (...)'`
(with geometry in srid 3857 as well), I always get empty result (even for geometry I am sure they do have intersection with `GeoData` objects).

What have I misunderstood?

Configuration:

- `Django==1.9.10`
- `django-filter==0.15.2`
- `djangorestframework==3.4.7`
- `djangorestframework-gis==0.10.1`

Comment: Assuming their table compatibility it may not work. Please try updating to 0.11.2. The question is quite old. Did it worked for you?

Comment: is there postgres with postgis behind?

Comment: Yes there is a postgres database with postgis. I never managed to get it work but will try to give it a try with newer versions (postgis has also been upgraded since the question).